Wires branching in parallel with lipo battery and how would the current behave
If I have a 45C, 1.8Ah lipo battery (81A?) that I want to connect to a constant current driver that can only take up to 10A, would it be possible to use 8 wire branches (with no components) in parallel with the lipo and one branch containing the driver as would the current into the driver be 9A (81A/9 branches = 9A through each branch < 10A)? Is this how it works or would there be a short circuit?

8 branches in parallel with your battery will only short it out 8 times.

@John  What's the purpose of the "8 wire branches (with no components) in parallel with the lipo" ?

@NickAlexeev I wanted to split the 81A of current into smaller amounts so each branched wire would have less current flowing through so that the driver in one of the branches wouldn't blow out. Is this the wrong way of doing it? Better ways?

Your constant current driver (or any other load) will only draw the current it requires, providing that the source can supply at least that current.
The battery will not force its rated current through the circuit - that rating only shows the maximum current the battery should be asked to deliver.  There is no need to "draw off the excess" current.

Thanks for answering however I still don't understand (the method I've attempted to outline or otherwise) how I could use a 45C 1.8Ah lipo with a driver that can only intake a max of 15A. (wrongly I suppose) I thought that maybe if I had 9 parallel branches off the lipo, one containing the driver, the current to the driver would be reduced but is this true or is there an obvious flaw in my understanding? If so, are there other ways I could reduce current to the driver from a high c rating lipo?

As I said, the battery will not force its maximum rated current through a load.  The load (your constant current driver) will only draw the current it requires.

I directly attached the lipo to the input of a constant current driver and the outputs attached just to an ammeter but the driver still blew out immediately as it took more current than it could handle. Could you please explain why this happened

What is the battery voltage, and what are the specs (or make/model) of the current driver?  What current did the ammeter show?

battery was 4S 45C 1800mah, driver was 300W/20A and can take any voltage from around 2V to 60V. It blew out before the ammeter could even take a definite reading (the reading was increasing rapidly for the split second I observed before the driver blew out, also ammeter was on output side of driver). So why do you think this happened and how would I ever be able to adjust current output from the driver if it always blows out before I even have the chance?
